# replacing Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, elementary

I wiped my PC laptop and installed Ubuntu 16 on it. I like it, but my wife uses the laptop more and wants to use elemntaryOS instead.
I'd like to install elementaryOS ALONGSIDE ubuntu if possible, so I made a live USB  for elementary and plugged it into my ubuntu laptop. I rebooted the laptop, but it auto-booted to ubuntu without letting me see the grub interface allowing me to chose linux versions to boot (for clarity, it's also never given me that option before either).

My question is, what do I do to either get my laptop to boot from USB, or allow me to chose the boot source?
I've tried installing grub2 (in an effort to change grub settings allowing me to chose boot options), but when I run the command

```
sudo apt-get grub2-common
```

I get this

```
[Waiting for headers]
```

and it sits like this for a LONG time (I waited for 15 minutes before finally hitting ctrl-c to quit).

I've been told that in order to get both linux distros, I'd need to wipe and install elementaryOS first, then ubuntu (which plays nice with other linux distros already installed on a machine), but I can't even figure out how to wipe my laptop again at this point, nor would I seem to be able to boot from a USB once I've installed my distro of choice.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm... how did you make the live USB for ElementaryOS? (what method did you use to put the ISO file on there?)

Comment: I used Lili USB creator on my Windows 10 computer: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download

Comment: You need to set your laptop to boot from the USB - it has nothing to do with the installation of Ubuntu you already have. This varies with different laptops, your best bet might be to google "model of laptop" + "USB boot" - usually, you need to set this in the BIOS, or, on some laptops, you can hit a certain key during the boot process (right when you see the manufacturer logo when first turning on), often F2 or F12. If you still can't boot, try again using the recommended way of creating USBs using Rufus: https://elementary.io/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium

Comment: Also, once you boot from the USB, when you're in the installer, it will offer to install alongside Ubuntu - you don't need to wipe and instal elementary first. Elementary is based on Ubuntu, and, under the hood (Including installation and the recommended way to make USBs for it), is pretty much exactly the same as regular Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what JonasCz suggested and googled the model of my laptop (HP Stream 11) and found that immediately upon restart or power-up, I had to hold the esc button to enter the BIOS. This allowed me to chose the USB as the boot target and I was able to install ElementaryOS on the laptop.

I was *not* however, give the option on the installation guide to install "alongside" ubuntu, and was only given the option of creating a separate partition on which to install ElementaryOS, or to "erase Ubuntu and install ElementaryOS". This didn't end up upsetting me much, as I decided that I don't use the laptop enough to really need ubuntu on it for my own personal purposes, so I just did a clean format/install of ElementaryOS and now I'm happy.

thanks for all the input, folks!